# Android Studio how to delete folders under java module?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-module, project-structure

I want to have a java module name is features.And I want to delete folders [inside that module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKmPE.png) which names are main and test.I can't delete that two modules from android studio.Even I try to delete them in the folder they are still inside the features module for Android Studio.I also restarted the android studio after delete the folders, but still it didn't effect.
How can I convert that structure to  [structure like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRYGV.png).

Answer (score 2):

Go into your `settings.gradle` file and delete the `include` line for that module.

Then sync your Android Studio.

Then you will be able to delete the folders.

(At the moment you cannot delete the modules because the IDE doesn't let you delete registered gradle modules.)

Comment: I tried but still can't delete the folders.

Comment: Did you allow Android Studio to gradle sync? (refresh Gradle in the IDE). Once you do that, the little blue square in your screenshots will disappear and you will be able to delete the folder

Comment: Yeah but when I delete the include line I can't see the features folder in android studio anymore.

Comment: Change your view to "Project" instead of "Android" (in the top left, there is a dropdown)

Comment: Still same sadly it didn't effect again :(
I just added a list library inside the module maybe it effects too but I am not sure.